# Super privilege vs Root account

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I am wondering the differences between a user that has the Super privilege in MySQL and the root user which has all the privileges?

Comment: The root user has privileges regarding commands run in the host system, whereas the MySQL user has privileges regarding running MySQL commands. I am not sure that the root user is necessarily a super-user of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a default configuration of mysql has a predifened privileged user named root, allowed to login from localhost without a password. that user can be changed as any other user in the mysql server

Comment: In terms of rights once SUPER is granted to a new user does that user have similar accesses than root? Does that user basically become root?

Comment: if i remember correcktly, all user with SUPER are equal, that includes root unless you remove SUPER from root.